# SQL Server connectionStringName needed WebSecurity

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, security

I'm really sorry but I think I can't figure out a very trivial thing. I am trying to get started with WebSecurity (asp.net MVC), but the initial method asks for a connection string.

- I have a SQL Server 2012 edition installed.
- Created a database "Users"

Where can I find the connection string?

(I did manage to create a database + tables using EF code first, so I know things are installed properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the specifics (userid, password and servername) for your install, but this website can help with the syntax/format:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Comment: Hey, thx for the help! Is this what I am looking for?

Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword; 

Isn't it a bit weird to throw my credentials in hard-coded? And the server name is equal to my PC name. Where can I find the instance name?

Comment: I am probably being an idiot but this is what I entered: WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
        "Server=WS050129\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Users;User Id=domainxxxx\xxxx;Password=xxxxx;", 
        "UserProfile", 
        "UserId", 
        "UserName", 
        true);